# Knockout not updating page with current data

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-mapping-plugin

I am having trouble with knockout not updating my view properly... what happens is I make an ajax call to get my view data then use knockout to render it. On subsequent requests I make an ajax call to get the view data and then update the page with the new stuff.

The problem is that on call 2,3,4,etc... The page is not updating with the new data. I am using the mapping plugin which may be the problem.

```
if (filterLogModel == null) {
    filterLogModel = ko.mapping.fromJS(data);
    ko.applyBindings(filterLogModel, document.getElementById("dvFilterLog"));
} else {
    ko.mapping.fromJS(data, filterLogModel);
}
```

I thought this was the correct pattern to use but maybe not?

Things I've checked already:
1 - That the new data coming in IS different
2 - Ran through the debugger and the first request does go through the IF block and subsequent requests go through the ELSE block.

if the data returned contains no data part of my html has a condition for it

```
<div id="filterLogResults">
<!-- ko if: $data.length <= 0 -->
    <p class="attention">There are no errors for this task.</p>
<!-- /ko -->
<!-- ko if: $data.length > 0 -->
    <table class="tbl">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Description</th>
                <th>Value 1</th>
                <th>Operator</th>
                <th>Value 2</th>
                <th>Corrective Action</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody data-bind="foreach: $data">
            <tr>
                <td class="nowrap" data-bind="text:Description"></td>
                <td class="nowrap" data-bind="text:Value1"></td>
                <td class="nowrap" data-bind="text:OperatorName"></td>
                <td class="nowrap" data-bind="text:Value2"></td>
                <td class="main" data-bind="text:CorrectiveAction"></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
<!-- /ko -->
</div>
```

and the view does update and tell me there is no results... but when there is data it's like it's displaying a cached view or something and not the new data.

One other thing I noticed. If the first request contains some data. The second request contains no data. The third request contains some data. - in this case the 3rd request will show the new data and not the data from the first request. It only appears to happen when there are 2 requests in a row that have data that the view doesn't update.

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Edit: Full JS

```
function getFilterLogs(suppressErrors, callback) {
    $("#filterLogResults").hide();
    if (!g_objCommon.isBoolean(suppressErrors)) {
        suppressErrors = false;
    }
    if (filterLogAjaxRequest != null) {
        filterLogAjaxRequestAborted = true;
        filterLogAjaxRequest.abort();
    }
    g_objCommon.showLoading();
    filterLogAjaxRequest = $.ajax({
        cache: false,
        type: "GET",
        url: absoluteRootPath + "api/Tasks/GetFilterLogs?id=" + g_nWorklistId,
        contentType: "application/json",
        success: function (data) {
            filterLogAjaxRequest = null;
            g_objCommon.hideLoading();
            if (filterLogModel == null) {
                filterLogModel = ko.mapping.fromJS(data);
                ko.applyBindings(filterLogModel, document.getElementById("dvFilterLog"));
            } else {
                ko.mapping.fromJS(data, {}, filterLogModel);
            }
            if ($.isFunction(callback)) {
                callback(data.length);
            }
            $("#filterLogResults").show();
            $("#filterLogResults .tbl").show();
        },
        error: function () {
            filterLogAjaxRequest = null;
            g_objCommon.hideLoading();
            if (!filterLogAjaxRequestAborted) {
                if (!suppressErrors) {
                    g_objCommon.showErrorModal("There was an error loading the errors.", undefined);
                }
                if ($.isFunction(callback)) {
                    callback(0);
                }
                $("#filterLogResults .attention").show();
                $("#filterLogResults .tbl").hide();
                $("#filterLogResults").show();
            }
            filterLogAjaxRequestAborted = false;
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: I have a simple example here http://jsfiddle.net/sujesharukil/z8vpx/, is this the functionality you are looking for?

Answer (score 2):

I find that the mapping plugin sometimes doesn't update the view model unless there is a mapping object added to the list of parameters sent through to it:

```
ko.mapping.fromJS(data, {}, filterLogModel);
```

Comment: Can you add the code that makes the call to get the data too then, need a bit more to go on.